# PowerBI - Publish report with Api

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I have two tenants, one for Development and one for Production
We develop the reports from PowerBI Desktop and publish the pbix by publishing directly from PowerBI Desktop

To publish the content on both tenants I have to switch accounts every time and data connection

I wanted to avoid doing this by trying to use some PowerBI API to publish the pbix automatically on both tenants
Since the data connection is saved inside the pbix, through the import API I can only upload to my workspace on one tenant and not on the other
Through the Import groups/xxx/imports?datasetDisplayName=xxx api I get the following error : {"error":{"code":"PowerBIModelNotFoundException","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBIModelNotFoundException"," parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

How can I tell it to ignore the connection? I am only interested in importing the report and then changing the connection later

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered creating your development workspaces in the same tenant as Production and using PBI deployment pipelines to promote the artifacts?